from_csv schema option requests DDL but no possibility to create DDL
The from_csv function https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_csv.html , used to read a csv column in a dataframe, has a schema option. However this schema is expected to be a DDL string.
Is there a way to generate a DDL string from a StructType?
My problem with that is if I have a schema (StructType) I find no way in pyspark to generate a DDL string. The only way is to create a dataframe then access the java functions using _jf but this is not compatible with Spark Connect which is our way of developing.

Does this answer your question? 'StructType' object has no attribute 'toDDL'

In F.from_csv you can use the string returned by df.schema.simpleString():
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [
    ('1,ABC', ),
    ('2,ABC', ),
    ('3,ABC', ),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['csv_line'])
parsed_col = F.from_csv('csv_line', schema='struct<id:int,string_col:string>')

df2 = df.select(parsed_col.alias('parsed_col'))
df2.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- parsed_col: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- string_col: string (nullable = true)

df2.select('parsed_col.*').show(10, False)

# +---+----------+
# |id |string_col|
# +---+----------+
# |1  |ABC       |
# |2  |ABC       |
# |3  |ABC       |
# +---+----------+


I thought I tried it but I will again. Thank you
